# Where to ask questions about Android

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Android phones are computers and have power-users who want to make the most of them. Except these power users have been exiled from superuser.com <s>by the evil-tyrant (qq)</s> and left to ask their questions on inferior sites. Where should they go?

Comment: thanks for asking!  take a look at [Where to ask questions that aren't Super User questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41570/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions) ... sadly i can't take credit for the current evil anti-android policy, only it's evil implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Questions about programming for Android should go to [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Otherwise, they are off topic for superuser.

See:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42146/android-questions-on-superuser-getting-closed-as-not-computer-related
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13289/is-asking-phone-questions-permitted-on-superuser
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42164/can-we-start-a-smartphone-site

Answer (score 2):

The Android StackExchange has been around for a while and is fairly active:

https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I get a DNS failure trying to access the link you provide.

Comment: @ProfK: Updated (It was pointing to the old one that was around when this question was asked years ago, there's a new one now).